# Relationship between 2 definitions of sin. One using differential equations and one using the unit circle.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

I know of 2 ways to define the sine function:

1. The height of a point on the unit circle given the arc length.
2. The solution to the differential equation $f''(\theta)=-f(\theta)$

I know it can also be defined in terms of complex exponentials, but that seems to me to be a different way of writing method #2.

Method #1 is defined using the fact that sine and cosine (a shifted sine) can describe the y and x coordinates of the unit circle, respectively. That means that $sin^2(\theta) + sin^2(\theta+\pi/4) = 1$

My question is how the seemingly unrelated definition of sine as the solution to a differential equation (#2), comes out to be such that it forms a circle as described above.

Comment: You might be interested in the exposition of the properties of the sine and cosine functions given in "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Rudin.  Look up "Exponential function" in the index.  In my copy it's in Chapter 8, "Further Topics in the Theory of Series", but I have an old edition and I'm not sure where this topic falls in the current edition.